# "Getting 'KeePassTestSuite.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command' error when running Ranorex test suite in Jenkins"

Tags: jenkins

I am facing an issue when trying to run a Ranorex test suite through Jenkins. I have a Jenkins job configured to execute a Ranorex test suite (KeePassTestSuite.rxtst), but I keep encountering the following error:

'KeePassTestSuite.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Here are the key details of my setup:

- Jenkins is installed and running on [specify your environment].
- I have a Ranorex test suite file named KeePassTestSuite.rxtst.
- I am using the Jenkins Ranorex plugin (provide version if applicable).
- In my Jenkins job configuration, I have specified the path to KeePassTestSuite.rxtst.

I have checked the following:

- The .rxtst file is correctly located in my Jenkins workspace.
- The .exe file (KeePassTestSuite.exe) is supposed to be generated by Ranorex when building the test suite.

However, I am unsure why Jenkins is trying to execute an .exe file and encountering this error. Can someone please help me troubleshoot and resolve this issue? What could be causing Jenkins to attempt to execute the .exe file, and how can I fix it?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!